# ERROR TypeError: _co.function is not a function

Tags: angular

This is the error I get when trying to make the child call a method of the parent:

[image]

The child is favorite component.
The method `onFavoriteChange()` exists in the parent, but it's not triggered.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Ivans-world';
  post = {
    title:"Titulo",
    isFavorite: true
  }

  OnFavoriteChange(){  
    console.log("App Component. Triggered OnChanges(). Yupi!");
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<favorite   
       [is-favorite] = "post.isFavorite"  
       (change)  = "onFavoriteChange()"  
></favorite>
```

favorite.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { empty } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css'],
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('is-favorite') isFavorite: boolean;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  OnClick(){
    this.isFavorite = !(this.isFavorite);
    this.change.emit(); 
  } 

  ngOnInit() {
  } 
}
```

Comment: camelcase OnFavoriteChange in AppComponent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In app.component.html change

```
(change)  = "onFavoriteChange()"
```

to (first capital letter)

```
(change)  = "OnFavoriteChange()"
```

Comment: Yes! this was the problem. I will check your answer as the one that solved my problem as soon as the system allows me to.